# Cocos2D: Sprites fail to be removed when adding them with a class method

Tags: class, methods, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

In my method declaration in an alternate class, I pass a CCLayer pointer of which the sprite is added to and a sprite and spritesheet pointer:

```
+(void) toggleSeedSelectionScreen:(CCLayer*)layer 
                   withSeedSprite:(CCSprite*)seedSprite
              withSeedSpriteSheet:(CCSpriteBatchNode*)seedSpriteSheet;
```

In my .m in the toggleSeedSelectionScreen method, I add the spritesheet and sprite like:

```
[seedSpriteSheet addChild:seedSprite];
[layer addChild:seedSpriteSheet z:14];
```

This works fine.  What appears to be acting strange, is that when a method is called in my CCLayer (layer) to remove the seedSpriteSheet, nothing happens.

```
[self removeChild:seedSpriteSheet cleanup:YES];
```

When the class method used to be a method in layer, it worked fine.  Any obvious reasons why?

It seems that after it's added to layer, it doesn't know it's parent object in console by typing **po seedSprite**.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint and stepping through the code in the cocos2d library yet?  (Aside: this is one of the many glorious benefits to open source libraries!)

Comment: "When the class method used to be a method in layer, it worked fine.??????"
I am not able to understand this... Please elaborate..
Generally this self denotes the object of the layer class you made.. So if its a class method. This self will represent to your class. Class is not parent of sprite sheet. your class object is parent.

Comment: Nikhil: My method used to be in the same class as my main CCLayer that has the update method.  Now, to make things look cleaner in my main CCLayer, the method is now in a different class.

Comment: HachiEthan: I tried a bit of that, but I'll keep doing detective work, thanks.

Comment: I guess the thing is the spriteSheet is being added to something, I just don't know what, and I don't know why it shouldn't be the CCLayer that I'm pointing to self in my main CCLayer class.

Answer (score 1):

try  `[seedSpriteSheet  removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];`

edit: you said it worked when you changed it to a instance method on the layer ..so why not do something like this :`[[[myobject alloc]init] <instance method> ];`. I know it works becuase i used it

Comment: Does not work. Shouldn't that be seedSprite and not seedSpriteSheet? But seedSprite also does not work.

Comment: you know what i dont understand? why do you use class method for this?

Comment: skytz: I want to make my main CCLayer class smaller so it's easier to read, and many of the object pointers that are sent to the class method are referred to a bunch in my main CCLayer, so I keep them around. Do you have a better approach in mind?

Comment: In the instance method am I supposed to call layer or self on adding a child? When I call self, I don't see anything on the screen, and when I call layer, I see it, but when it makes the method call to remove it, it doesn't remove just like the class method. On the CCMenuItemImage target I found that I need to use layer because I use self it crashes because it's nil.